# How do you initialize a point as a linear combination of 2 others in metapost?

Tags: diagrams, metapost, vector

I am trying to initialize a new point as a linear combination of 2 others as a first step to draw a fancy line.

Currently I am trying this:

```
vardef line(expr pfirst, psecond)=

    tangent := psecond-pfirst;
    draw u*pfirst--u*psecond withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor black;

enddef;
```

I also tried without the colon and putting the expression in parentheses.

All I get as an error is:

```
 >> tangent
(luamplib)               >> (-1,-1)
(luamplib)               ! Equation cannot be performed (numeric=pair).
(luamplib)               <to be read again>
```

Comment: Presumably your `pfirst` and `psecond` are pairs.  Without declaring a type for `tangent`, it's assumed to be a numeric variable (hence the error).  Add `save tangent; pair tangent;` as the first line of your vardef.

Comment: that worked, I was missing the declaration

Comment: That gets me every now and then as well. Not sure why I answered in the comments...if you'd like I can make it an answer.

Comment: Make it an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undeclared variables in `metapost` are assumed to be `numeric`.  Thus, something like

```
beginfig(0);
  % myvar undeclared-> assumed to be numeric
  myvar:=0;
endfig;
```

does not produce an error.  However,

```
beginfig(0);
% myvar undeclared-> assumed to be numeric 
% error because assigning the pair (0,0) to the numeric variable myvar.
  myvar:=(0,0);
endfig;
```

will give the same error as above.  You issue can therefore be solved by telling `metapost` that `tangent` is a `pair` variable:

```
vardef line(expr pfirst, psecond)=
    save tangent; % make tangent local to the vardef (if this is desired)
    pair tangent; % tell metapost that tangent will hold a pair
    tangent := psecond-pfirst;
    draw u*pfirst--u*psecond withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor black;

enddef;
```